# Capturing Images with Higher Depth in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, video-capture

By Using the VideoCapture class of OpenCV, I'm able to record 8 bits images from my webcam.
But, I need more values for Color. So, I'd probably need a 16bit or 24 bit image.
How to do that in OpenCV?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by: "But, I need more values for Color"? Why do you need more values? What do you mean by "more"? What is a possible use case?

Comment: Around a bright light source in my image, all there is a big blob of white pixels. I want to be able to quantize the colors in a finer way to get all shades of white

Comment: @RajathS did you try histogram equalization

Comment: @CanberkBaci Yes. I tried using it. It did not help.

Answer (score 2):

If your subject is stationery, then you could generate a cleaner image by averaging consecutive frames. There may even be some value in storing the result with a greater bit depth, but don't expect miracles — an 8-bit camera and an 8-bit video codec will never give you proper 16-bit video.

For example, here's a frame captured by a webcam in low light conditions. It's rather noisy:

[image: Webcam image of a boatyard in low light conditions]

And here's the result of averaging a hundred consecutive frames. It's better, but not perfect.

[image: Cleaner image obtained by averaging 100 consecutive frames from the same webcam]

Comment: @squeamih ossifrage What do you mean by averaging hundred consective frames ? its mean like getting consective frames from webcam and than take average of that 100 frames , or putting average algorithm on image for enhancement ?

Comment: @Ahmad Get a hundred consecutive frames, and average them together. With a single frame, there is nothing you can do to increase the pixel depth.

Comment: I've tried averaging.. Around a bright light source in my image, all there is a big blob of white pixels. I want to be able to quantize the colors in a finer way to get all shades of white

Comment: @RajathS It would help if you could provide some sample images to explain what you mean. But as a rule, if you're trying to extract information from an image that is mostly white, you would probably be be better off using a faster exposure or a smaller aperture.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage When I try to tweak the camera parameters using VideoCapture::set() method in OpenCV, it reports back with a message saying you are not allowed to set this property. I'll probably use V4L to tweak the image.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the webcams support only 8-bits per color channel. Make sure your camera supports higher depth; and do not use OpenCV to retrieve video for this case. OpenCV converts whole data to 8-bit & 3 channels.

Use camera manufacturer API (or a third party library like v4l) to retrieve the higher depth data, and push that data into an IplImage or Mat by hand. Something like:

```
// allocate Mat data
Mat frame(640, 480, CV_16UC3);;
// populate
loop{
frame.at<Vec3b>(i,j) = ImageReturnedByCamera.at(i,j);
}
```

Comment: But if we use good quality camera with opencv still it give us 8-bit image with low quality ?

Comment: I think opencv Video Capture class has a property for setting the codec (for supported cameras), but as I know you should write codec by yourself since the library has limited interface for high quality cameras. Example: uEye IDS https://code.google.com/p/low-cost-vision/source/browse/trunk/Vision/ueyeOpencv/include/UEyeOpenCV.hpp?r=260. Similar issues: http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/Need-to-perform-16-bit-single-channel-video-capture-or-capture-raw-bin-data-td5411180.html, http://forum.mesa-imaging.ch/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=151